# Find previous date in dataframe with same column category in R

Tags: r, dataframe, dplyr, data.table

I have the following data frame:

```
      Date.POSIXct       Date      WeekDay DayCategory Hour Holidays   value
1 2018-05-01 00:00:00 2018-05-01      MA    MA-MI-JU    0        0      30
2 2018-05-01 01:00:00 2018-05-01      MA    MA-MI-JU    1        0      80
3 2018-05-01 02:00:00 2018-05-01      MA    MA-MI-JU    2        0      42
4 2018-05-01 03:00:00 2018-05-01      MA    MA-MI-JU    3        0      90
5 2018-05-01 04:00:00 2018-05-01      MA    MA-MI-JU    4        0      95
6 2018-05-01 05:00:00 2018-05-01      MA    MA-MI-JU    5        0       5
```

DayCategory groups days of the week in the following way: Mondays goes to `LU` DayCategory. Tuesday, Wednesday and Thursdays go to `MA-MI-JU` DayCategory.
Friday goes to `VI`, Saturdays to `SA` and Sundays to `DO` Categories respectively.

I would like to find the `value` for the same `hour` in the previous day (`Date`) with the same `DayCategory`, while `Holidays` remains within the same group (e.g. if one instance has `holiday` 0 but previous day with same `DayCategory` has 1, we should lookv for the previous one, etc.)

As an intermediate step and to understand the process I would like to add a column `PreviousDaySameDayCategory` with the `Date` of the previous day that has the same `DayCategory` that the corresponding row. Some times it will be just the same `date` minus seven days ("LU","VI","SA","DO") but other days it will be just one day.

Reproducible data:

```
library(lubridate)
Date.POSIXct <- seq(as.POSIXct("2018-05-01"), as.POSIXct("2018-05-31"), "hour")
mydf <- as.data.frame(Date.POSIXct)
mydf$Date <- as.Date(substr(as.character(mydf$Date.POSIXct),1,10))
mydf$WeekDay <- substr(toupper((weekdays(mydf$Date))),1,2)
mydf$DayCategory <-as.factor(ifelse(mydf$WeekDay == "MA" | mydf$WeekDay == "MI" | mydf$WeekDay == "JU", 
                                    "MA-MI-JU", mydf$WeekDay))
mydf$Hour <- hour(mydf$Date.POSIXct)
mydf$Holidays <- c(rep(0, 24*7),rep(1, 24*7), rep(0, 24*16+1))
set.seed(123)
mydf$myvalue <- sample.int(101,size=nrow(mydf),replace=TRUE)
```

I have manually started the first days and craeted a vector of how the solution should look like:

```
  a <- rep(NA, 24)
  b <- mydf$value[1:24]
  c <- mydf$value[25:48]
  d <- rep(NA, 24)
  e <- rep(NA,24)
  f <- rep(NA,24)
  g <- rep(NA,24)
  h <- rep(NA,24)
  i <- mydf$value[169:192]
  solution <- c(a,b,c,d,e,f,g,h,i)
  solution
```

I would appreciate any hint in the thinking process to solve this kind of problems that I face with relative frequency.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is a `data.table` solution which uses a "grouped `shift()`" and multiple joins to copy `value` from the same `hour` of the `PreviousDaySameDayCategory`.

#### Create reproducible data

OP's code to create reproducible data was not fully reproducible because he used the `weekdays()` function which returns the weekday names in the current locale (which seems to be Spanish for the OP). To be independent of the current locale, I switched to `format(Date, "%u")` which returns the numbers 1 to 7 for Monday to Sunday. Furthermore, the `fct_collapse()` from the `forcats` package is used to collapse the days 2, 3, and 4 (Tuesday to Thursday) into one factor level.

```
library(data.table)
# note that package lubridate is not required
myDT <- data.table(Date.POSIXct = seq(as.POSIXct("2018-05-01"), 
                                      as.POSIXct("2018-05-31"), "hour"))
myDT[, Date := as.Date(Date.POSIXct)]
myDT[, Weekday := format(Date, "%u")]
myDT[, DayCategory := forcats::fct_collapse(Weekday, "234" = c("2", "3", "4"))]
myDT[, hour := hour(Date.POSIXct)]
myDT[, Holidays := c(rep(0, 24 * 7), rep(1, 24 * 7), rep(0, 24 * 16 + 1))]
set.seed(123)
myDT[, myvalue := sample.int(101, size = nrow(mydf), replace = TRUE)]
```

#### Intermediate step: `PreviousDaySameDayCategory`

The sample data set consists of hourly data but in order to determine the `PreviousDaySameDayCategory` we need to work day-wise and thus only have to deal with the unique values of `Date`, `DayCategory`, and `Holidays`. The data is grouped by `DayCategory` and the `Holidays` indicator. For each group separately, the previous day is picked by lagging `Date`. As the result of `shift()` operations depend on the order of rows the dataset has been ordered before shifting.

```
tmp <- unique(myDT[order(Date), .(Date, DayCategory, Holidays)])[
  , .(Date, PreviousDaySameDayCategory = shift(Date)), by = .(DayCategory, Holidays)][
    order(Date)]
tmp
```

> ```
>     DayCategory Holidays       Date PreviousDaySameDayCategory
>  1:         234        0 2018-05-01                       <NA>
>  2:         234        0 2018-05-02                 2018-05-01
>  3:         234        0 2018-05-03                 2018-05-02
>  4:           5        0 2018-05-04                       <NA>
>  5:           6        0 2018-05-05                       <NA>
>  6:           7        0 2018-05-06                       <NA>
>  7:           1        0 2018-05-07                       <NA>
>  8:         234        1 2018-05-08                       <NA>
>  9:         234        1 2018-05-09                 2018-05-08
> 10:         234        1 2018-05-10                 2018-05-09
> 11:           5        1 2018-05-11                       <NA>
> 12:           6        1 2018-05-12                       <NA>
> 13:           7        1 2018-05-13                       <NA>
> 14:           1        1 2018-05-14                       <NA>
> 15:         234        0 2018-05-15                 2018-05-03
> 16:         234        0 2018-05-16                 2018-05-15
> 17:         234        0 2018-05-17                 2018-05-16
> 18:           5        0 2018-05-18                 2018-05-04
> 19:           6        0 2018-05-19                 2018-05-05
> 20:           7        0 2018-05-20                 2018-05-06
> 21:           1        0 2018-05-21                 2018-05-07
> 22:         234        0 2018-05-22                 2018-05-17
> 23:         234        0 2018-05-23                 2018-05-22
> 24:         234        0 2018-05-24                 2018-05-23
> 25:           5        0 2018-05-25                 2018-05-18
> 26:           6        0 2018-05-26                 2018-05-19
> 27:           7        0 2018-05-27                 2018-05-20
> 28:           1        0 2018-05-28                 2018-05-21
> 29:         234        0 2018-05-29                 2018-05-24
> 30:         234        0 2018-05-30                 2018-05-29
> 31:         234        0 2018-05-31                 2018-05-30
>     DayCategory Holidays       Date PreviousDaySameDayCategory
> ```

For days 3 and 4 (Wednesdays and Thursday) the preceeding Tuesday and Wednesday, resp., of the same week are picked. For day 2 (Tuesday) the preceeding Thursday of the preceeding week is picked *if* both weeks have the same holiday indicator set. If the preceeding week has a different holiday indicator the most recent Thursday of the same holiday period is picked. This is why, e.g., the 2018-05-03 is picked in row 15.

#### Copying `value` from matching `PreviousDaySameDayCategory`

This is done in two steps. First, the hourly values are picked from the matching `PreviousDaySameDayCategory` by joining with the matching days table `tmp`:

```
tmp2 <- myDT[tmp, on = .(Date = PreviousDaySameDayCategory), .(Date = i.Date, hour, myvalue), nomatch = 0L] 
tmp2
```

> ```
>            Date hour myvalue
>   1: 2018-05-02    0      30
>   2: 2018-05-02    1      80
>   3: 2018-05-02    2      42
>   4: 2018-05-02    3      90
>   5: 2018-05-02    4      95
>  ---                        
> 500: 2018-05-31   19      39
> 501: 2018-05-31   20       1
> 502: 2018-05-31   21       1
> 503: 2018-05-31   22     101
> 504: 2018-05-31   23      11
> ```

Second, a new column `previousValue` in `myDT` is created by *updating in a join* which contains the corresponding value from `PreviousDaySameDayCategory`:

```
myDT[tmp2, on = .(Date, hour), previousValue := i.myvalue]
```

Here, the first two days of the result are shown:

```
myDT[Date %between% c(as.Date("2018-05-01"), as.Date("2018-05-02"))]
```

> ```
>            Date.POSIXct       Date Weekday DayCategory hour Holidays myvalue previousValue
>  1: 2018-05-01 00:00:00 2018-05-01       2         234    0        0      30            NA
>  2: 2018-05-01 01:00:00 2018-05-01       2         234    1        0      80            NA
>  3: 2018-05-01 02:00:00 2018-05-01       2         234    2        0      42            NA
>  4: 2018-05-01 03:00:00 2018-05-01       2         234    3        0      90            NA
>  5: 2018-05-01 04:00:00 2018-05-01       2         234    4        0      95            NA
>  6: 2018-05-01 05:00:00 2018-05-01       2         234    5        0       5            NA
>  7: 2018-05-01 06:00:00 2018-05-01       2         234    6        0      54            NA
>  8: 2018-05-01 07:00:00 2018-05-01       2         234    7        0      91            NA
>  9: 2018-05-01 08:00:00 2018-05-01       2         234    8        0      56            NA
> 10: 2018-05-01 09:00:00 2018-05-01       2         234    9        0      47            NA
> 11: 2018-05-01 10:00:00 2018-05-01       2         234   10        0      97            NA
> 12: 2018-05-01 11:00:00 2018-05-01       2         234   11        0      46            NA
> 13: 2018-05-01 12:00:00 2018-05-01       2         234   12        0      69            NA
> 14: 2018-05-01 13:00:00 2018-05-01       2         234   13        0      58            NA
> 15: 2018-05-01 14:00:00 2018-05-01       2         234   14        0      11            NA
> 16: 2018-05-01 15:00:00 2018-05-01       2         234   15        0      91            NA
> 17: 2018-05-01 16:00:00 2018-05-01       2         234   16        0      25            NA
> 18: 2018-05-01 17:00:00 2018-05-01       2         234   17        0       5            NA
> 19: 2018-05-01 18:00:00 2018-05-01       2         234   18        0      34            NA
> 20: 2018-05-01 19:00:00 2018-05-01       2         234   19        0      97            NA
> 21: 2018-05-01 20:00:00 2018-05-01       2         234   20        0      90            NA
> 22: 2018-05-01 21:00:00 2018-05-01       2         234   21        0      70            NA
> 23: 2018-05-01 22:00:00 2018-05-01       2         234   22        0      65            NA
> 24: 2018-05-01 23:00:00 2018-05-01       2         234   23        0     101            NA
> 25: 2018-05-02 00:00:00 2018-05-02       3         234    0        0      67            30
> 26: 2018-05-02 01:00:00 2018-05-02       3         234    1        0      72            80
> 27: 2018-05-02 02:00:00 2018-05-02       3         234    2        0      55            42
> 28: 2018-05-02 03:00:00 2018-05-02       3         234    3        0      61            90
> 29: 2018-05-02 04:00:00 2018-05-02       3         234    4        0      30            95
> 30: 2018-05-02 05:00:00 2018-05-02       3         234    5        0      15             5
> 31: 2018-05-02 06:00:00 2018-05-02       3         234    6        0      98            54
> 32: 2018-05-02 07:00:00 2018-05-02       3         234    7        0      92            91
> 33: 2018-05-02 08:00:00 2018-05-02       3         234    8        0      70            56
> 34: 2018-05-02 09:00:00 2018-05-02       3         234    9        0      81            47
> 35: 2018-05-02 10:00:00 2018-05-02       3         234   10        0       3            97
> 36: 2018-05-02 11:00:00 2018-05-02       3         234   11        0      49            46
> 37: 2018-05-02 12:00:00 2018-05-02       3         234   12        0      77            69
> 38: 2018-05-02 13:00:00 2018-05-02       3         234   13        0      22            58
> 39: 2018-05-02 14:00:00 2018-05-02       3         234   14        0      33            11
> 40: 2018-05-02 15:00:00 2018-05-02       3         234   15        0      24            91
> 41: 2018-05-02 16:00:00 2018-05-02       3         234   16        0      15            25
> 42: 2018-05-02 17:00:00 2018-05-02       3         234   17        0      42             5
> 43: 2018-05-02 18:00:00 2018-05-02       3         234   18        0      42            34
> 44: 2018-05-02 19:00:00 2018-05-02       3         234   19        0      38            97
> 45: 2018-05-02 20:00:00 2018-05-02       3         234   20        0      16            90
> 46: 2018-05-02 21:00:00 2018-05-02       3         234   21        0      15            70
> 47: 2018-05-02 22:00:00 2018-05-02       3         234   22        0      24            65
> 48: 2018-05-02 23:00:00 2018-05-02       3         234   23        0      48           101
>            Date.POSIXct       Date Weekday DayCategory hour Holidays myvalue previousValue
> ```

#### Verification

The result is in line with OP's expectations

```
identical(myDT[, previousValue[seq_along(solution)]], solution)
```

> ```
> [1] TRUE
> ```

Comment: Thanks a lot for the detailed explanation. I am not used to use data.table and it took me some time to figure out about the `.()` syntax and the `on =` feature but after some research I think I have understood the process.

Comment: I have checked the solution in a large dataframe with similar characteristics and seems to work perfectly. 

Thanks.

Comment: I have realized this answer does not consider that there are days with 23h and days with 25hours due to daylight savings time shifting in Europe. Will try to adapt it.

Comment: The question & sample data did not mention day light saving time shifts. Time zones and day light savings impose issues which are not restricted to Europe. Perhaps, the easiest way is to convert local times to UTC when reading the data. Then, there should be no need to adapt the code.

Comment: Thanks! I am getting used to daylight savings programming related issues, will try to go deeper in this matter. I have found this post that might be useful: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2532729/daylight-saving-time-and-time-zone-best-practices .

Answer (score 2):

OP has posted the same question in the Data Science section as well. I am including the same solution I have there here case it might help others.
It is similar to Uwe's solution but with the dplyr library instead.

```
library(dplyr)
rankedDf <- mydf %>%
  group_by(DayCategory, Hour, Holidays) %>%
  arrange(Date) %>%
  mutate(rowRank = order(Date), previousRowRank = order(Date) - 1) %>%
  left_join(., ., by = c("previousRowRank" = "rowRank", "DayCategory", "Hour", "Holidays")) %>%
  select(
  Date.POSIXct = Date.POSIXct.x,
  Date = Date.x,
  WeekDay = WeekDay.x,
  DayCategory,
  Hour,
  Holidays,
  myvalue = myvalue.x,
  PreviousDaySameDayCategory = Date.y,
  PreviousValueSameDayCategory = myvalue.y
)
print.data.frame(rankedDf)
```

P.S. love the way Uwe changes the original sample code.

Comment: Thanks the Lyrist for your answer. Maybe we should just copy your answer from Data Science Exchange Community and close the answer there, is that ok w you? 

I understand your reassoning there, however I have not been able to implement in in the code with satisfactory results. I will keep trying as I am more familiar with dplyr than data.table and would like to get it with both packages to practice.